# Why is ng-submit not submitting and updating model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-submit

http://plnkr.co/edit/0W4ATi7loAKk94Cnj3lz?p=preview

A simple Angular app, not sure why the `ng-submit` isn't firing the `createMeetup` function

**HTML**

```
<!-- Meetups View -->
<div ng-controller="meetupsController">
    <h1>There are {{meetupsCount}} meetups</h1> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="meetup in meetups">
            {{meetup.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form ng-submit="createMeetup()">
    <input ng-model="meetupName" type="text" placeholder="Meetup name"></input>
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('meetupsApp', [])

.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.meetupsCount = 10;

    $scope.meetups = [
        { name: "MEAN SF Developers" },
        { name: "Some other meetup" },
    ]

    $scope.createMeetup = function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $scope.meetups.push({ name: $scope.meetupName });
        $scope.meetupName = '';
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form element is placed outside of your controller's scope.

```
<!-- Meetups View -->
<div ng-controller="meetupsController">
    <h1>There are {{meetupsCount}} meetups</h1> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="meetup in meetups">
            {{meetup.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="createMeetup()">
           <input ng-model="meetupName" type="text" placeholder="Meetup name"></input>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Was following along a new full-stack tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEE7DY2AYvI I'm used to adding my main controllers to the body tag, and here it was just an isolated div